# How do I disable the review of comments?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want comments not to be underlined with green lines…
I think PhpStorm is slow because of this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Proofreading an either disable spell checking entirely or change the severity to no highlighting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the options that you want to disable.

```
File >> Settings >> Editor >> Inspections >> Proofreading >> Typo
```

[image]

Or you can add that word to the dictionary

[image]